# Zend Framework 2 route not pointing to the right action

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

So in my `module.config.php` I have two routes, one that is pointing to the `Panel/Index` controller and it's working, and another one, which is pointing to `Panel\Ads` the problem is that this one, has a child route, called `edit` and when I access the route `site.com/panel/ads/edit/34` is still poiting to the action `index` from the `Ads` controller, it should point to the `edit` action. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'panel' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/panel',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Panel\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'panel' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/panel',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Panel\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'actions' => 'index'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ))),


            'ads' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/panel/ads',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Panel\Controller\Ads',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'ads' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/panel/ads',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Panel\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Ads',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'actions' => 'index'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),

                    'edit' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/edit/[:id]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Ads',
                                'action' => 'edit',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'actions' => 'edit'
                            ),
                        ),
                    )

                     )) 
        )),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Panel\Controller\Index' => 'Panel\Controller\IndexController',
            'Panel\Controller\Add' => 'Panel\Controller\AddController',
            'Panel\Controller\Ads' => 'Panel\Controller\AdsController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: @doydoy44 Why you suggested to remove the `zend-framework` tag? This doesn't make sense. Official language tag should be added.

Comment: @RahilWazir: I suggest to remove zend-framework tag because it's a problem about zend-framewok2 (version2), not a problem about zend-framework (version1). The zend-framework tag is about the zend-framework Version1

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the issue is with the constrains in your `edit` route. Constraints should be regular expression patterns that restrict matching of variables in the route. For example, you might want to specify that `id` in the URL must be numeric. Your edit route has constraints for `controller` and `action`, neither of which are variables in the route, so I'm not exactly sure what ZF will do with those.

There are a couple of other issues with your configuration. Firstly, route names must be unique. You are defining two routes called `panel`, and two routes called `ads`. More importantly, keys in a PHP array must be unique, so in each case, the second will overwrite the first.

Your first panel route and first ads route are both unecessary, as in each case the second route will match `site.com/panel` and `site.com/ads` anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the first panel route and also the first ads route, still doesn't work, I noticed if I change the action `index` in the `ads` route to `edit` than it points to edit, but the index action won't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'panel' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/panel', 
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Panel\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the errors was on the `edit-ad` route

```
),
'defaults' => array(
'actions' => 'edit'
```

That should be `action` without the `s` at the end, renamed and it worked!